# How to change DevExpress GridControl default theme in WPF control which is used in MFC

Tags: c#, wpf, mfc, devexpress

I am using a WPF Control (which is using DevExpress GridControl) inside MFC application.
I need to know a way to change it's default Blue theme.

I tried:

`DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = "Office2007Black";`

and it works fine, as lon as I am using this control within WPF application.
But when I put that control inside MFC application, it stops working.

Comment: I suggest you try to use the [ThemeManager.ThemeName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreThemeManager_ThemeNametopic) property in XAML?

Comment: I would suggest "Properties.Settings.Default.ThemeName = themeName;    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();"

Comment: @DmitryG  Unfortunately the project does not contain xaml file. It's done in C#

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade I am guessing you are referring to DevExpress.xpf.Grid.Core.Properties
But I get "Settings" does not exist in the assembly.

I do have assembly added to the project references. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with this magic line:

```
ThemeManager.SetThemeName(this, “Office2007Blue”);
```